# Potential leak in ceiling - second opinion on cause

Tags: plumbing, ceiling, leak, water-damage, leaks

Over the past few months I have noticed what looks like bubbling/peeling/flaking on part of my ceiling and I'm not sure what is causing it.
I suspect it might be water leaking from somewhere as both bathrooms are above the area but I would like a second opinion and any advice on what I should do.

[image: The whole affected area]

[image: Up close of the main area]

[image: What looks like water spots on the surface directly below]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What's above the ceiling here—attic? another floor?

Comment: @Huesmann OP says both bathrooms are above...

Comment: Water flows downhill, so it could be the bathrooms above, could be the roof leaking and running down to here before it shows up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to examine the rooms & flooring above, even if that means lifting the boards; as it's considerably easier & cheaper than fixing Victorian coving. If it really is impossible to reach above there without having to move toilets/bath etc, you can cut into the flat part of the ceiling, which is relatively easy to patch. Beware - the plasterwork will be filthy beyond compare above there.

If that's an outside wall, also check gutters, fall pipes & pointing. If it's a chimney breast, also check the chimney stack.

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspect when a bath is above a room with those issues is a toilet that has the wax seal leaking.

If your toilet discharges through the back, take a look.

It could be drains or pipes leaking under a sink or in the wall, but my experience is in most cases it's the toilet seal.

Look on the floor for any signs of water seeping.  If you have a tile floor, darker grout lines are a good indication of water leaking.

Bottom line, examine all the bath fixtures, before searching for something outside.

Comment: Hmm… I guess we don't know for sure yet, but I'd logged that ceiling as being UK. I've never been in a house in the US old enough to have that kind of coving. ;)

Comment: Sure, but the UK doesn't have toilets with wax rings ;)

Comment: The feed, flush or trap could leak. Usually you could tell which by visual inspection without lifting a board. If it's beyond the trap, then it's time to get the floor up. At the moment, though, it could equally by a worn flexi hose or something else quite simple. OP needs to go look.